# DBA Role permissions in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

What is the recommended permission set to assign to DBAs in AWS. Can I give full access to RDS to DBA. What are the security concerns I should looking out for

Comment: This question is not really programming related. Please update your question to show why it is programming related.

Answer (score 0):

There are several layers of security you may consider.

- Limit the network access - you may use [RDS Security Groups](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Overview.RDSSecurityGroups.html) to limit which VPC or IP has access to RDS endpoint or using the private endpoints. They are different [scenarios](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/USER_VPC.Scenarios.html) defined
- You may create users and their permission inside the database (depends on your chosen database engine)
- You may use [IAM to authenticate RDS users](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html)